# How to create edit and delete for table that receiving data in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I want to show all post from database with table, with the ability to delete and edit posts from the database.
It's my code:

```
<div id="addPost">
<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Author Name</th>
        <th>Author ID</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Content</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php
        // Check connection
        if (!can_connectToDBwithConstant()) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        // Create connection
        $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
        $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ID,post_author_name,post_author_id,post_date,post_title,post_content FROM  `wp_posts`");
            //php loop to load all post 
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)):
                $id = $row['ID'];
                $authorName = $row['post_author_name'];
                $authorID = $row['post_author_id'];
                $date = $row['post_date'];
                $title = $row['post_title'];
                $content = $row['post_content'];
        ?>

        <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $authorName; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $authorID; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $title; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $content; ?></td>
        <td>Edit | Delete</td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; mysqli_close($con); ?>
</table>
```

The problem is: How do we know which ones are selected posts to edit it or delete it?How can I do it?

Comment: You put all the data in the table, then when the user want's to "update" the data, you read all the data from the table and put the new data in the db. You could do it in a more complex fashion (if inputy changes, and inputz changes, then only read and store those), but given the limited number of values you have, what not just read and write them all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to solve this, one of them is by taggin the Edit and Delete labels or some other element ( td, tr or taking the value from the id field you already have). Here's a very simple (not the best but it can give a very clear idea of what the deal is with this things):

```
<td>
    <button id="edit_<?php echo $id ?>">Edit</button>
    <button id="delete_<?php echo $id ?>">Delete</button>
</td>
```

By this you can extrac the id value from button using Jquery o javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple.
You should be having a php script at server end to process the deletion of any post with a given ID.
Like if you are not using OOP, get the ID of the post to be deleted via $_GET or $_POST and then process deletion query and then redirect to the listing page.

```
<?php
    // Check connection
    if (!can_connectToDBwithConstant()) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    // Create connection
    $deleteID = $_GET['id'];
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE from TABLE_NAME where id_column = '".$deleteID."'");
header('Location: listin.php');
?>
```

And in the listing code -

```
<a href="www.hostname.com/process_delete.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"
```