# Delete Button in PHP isn't Working

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm trying to add a php button on to my site, however it doesn't seem to be working.

The delete php script is;

```
if(isset($_POST["delete"])) { 

   $delquery = "DELETE FROM emails WHERE ID=$_POST["delete"]"; 
   mysqli_query($connection, $delquery);

}
```

And the form looks like which is on the same file;

```
<form action="email-response.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
  <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete">
</form>
```

However whenever I clicked the delete button nothing is happening.

In relation to the reply saying that my $connection function is wrong, here is the function however its working as it is fetching my information for my posts.

```
define("DB_SERVER", "myservername");
define("DB_USER", "myusername"); //username
define("DB_PASS", "mypassword"); //password
define("DB_NAME", "mydbname"); // database name

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " .
        mysqli_connect_error() .
        " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
    );
} else {
    echo "connected";
}
```

Comment: WOW, enough code to solve your problem.

Comment: $connection is wrong i guess

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: What's the point of having the `$row['ID'];` when you hard code the delete to `18` ?

Comment: @Darren's right. Try changing `value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>"` to `value="18"` if that works, you'll know what to go for. Meaning, you'll need to add  another POST array for it.

Comment: The 18 is there to test if the delete function was working not the $row['ID']

Comment: `WHERE ID=$_POST["delete"]";` try `WHERE ID=$_POST['hidden']";` pretty sure that'll work. Would be much easier pre-assigning a variable though. Since your element is named `hidden` and not `delete`.

Comment: @Darren they've deleted their answer. For anyone else reading this, somebody else copied my answer and thinking to make it their own and feed off it. Thanks for having my back  Darren, cheers ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- He seems to be doing it a lot with a few other answers and also simple code-only ones... How can someone be that incompetent... anyways, great answer ;-) (*as always*)

Comment: @Darren People aren't stupid, they'll get wind of him, real fast; snakes can't hide forever. And thanks Darren, I appreciate it.

Comment: Also see [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element you wish to delete is named `hidden` and not `delete`.

- That is what your submit button is named as (delete).

Change your query to this:

```
if(isset($_POST["delete"]) && !empty($_POST["hidden"])){
   $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["hidden"]);
}

$delquery = "DELETE FROM emails WHERE ID='$id'"; 
mysqli_query($connection, $delquery) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection)){
  echo "It was really successful.";
}
```

- `isset($_POST["delete"])` is to check if the submit button was clicked.
- Using [`mysqli_affected_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) will show you if your query was truly successful.
  This is a function I've grown to use more often.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Sidenote: Using your present method, leaves you open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: I have made all the changes apart from the SQL injection which I didn't know about will fix that in the future thanks. However now I'm getting an error - Notice: Undefined variable: id in /home/u998846608/public_html/email-response.php on line 97 (line 97 is the link of the $delquery code)

Comment: @MatthewHammond Your query failed then. You'll need to show us the rest of your code where you're fetching `echo $row['ID']` from. `if(isset($_POST["delete"]) && !empty($_POST["hidden"])){` in my answer tests if it is set/not empty.

Comment: Is the a site which allows you to show more code than the 500 characters?

Comment: @MatthewHammond well, you can show the relevant part of the query. Plus, try changing `$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["hidden"]);` to `$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET["hidden"]);` I've a feeling that you'll need to use that, since I don't know what the rest of your code looks like. But am next to certain your query failed.

Comment: My fetch query looks like  <?php

        $_POST = "SELECT ID, fName, lName, eAddress, company, eSubject, eContent, time_stamp FROM emails ORDER BY ID DESC";
        // database columom rows name ----- database name
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $_POST);
    // result query code
    ?> with a while loop <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?> and then I create divs which I echo out the information.

Comment: @MatthewHammond silly me, I had `$connect` instead of `$connection`. I edited my answer with `$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["hidden"]);` try that now.

Comment: I have already noticed that and fixed it, however I still get them same error message,

Comment: @MatthewHammond but your query, that isn't right though. That's why it's failing. After seeing that in your comment. `$_POST = "SELECT ID` and `$result = mysqli_query($connection, $_POST);` can't do that. It's invalid syntax.

Comment: wow im an idiot been trying to work this out for the past 5 hours and didn't see that simple mistake, thank you so much for helping spot the noob error!!!! Its working perfectly now thanks once again!

Comment: plus either as I said earlier or `id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET["hidden"]);` since it's being populated from a SELECT query. Have a look at this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/21245186/ and a few of the answers in there.

Comment: @MatthewHammond In not accepting the answer and ticking the checkmark till it turns green near the up/down arrow next to my answer on the left, your question will remain in the unanswered category, where people will think the question is unsolved and still open. That's how the Stack system runs, in case you may not know.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection is good.

Here is the solution which will work and is simple:

Your form:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="to_delete" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete">
</form>
```

Your delete script:

```
 if(isset($_POST["delete"]))
{ 
 $delquery = "DELETE FROM user WHERE ID=".$_POST['to_delete'].""; 
 mysqli_query($connection, $delquery);
}
```

Comment: Why are you promoting bad practice and leaving the OP with an SQL Injection...?

Comment: @Darren where are these guys coming from? they're all flocking together I guess

Comment: @Darren if the question were a day older, I'd of put a protection on it. Yeah... I have that power ;)

Comment: Ravi; the question has already been solved, by "me" and a long time ago.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You have ALL the powers!! ;-)

Comment: @Darren hahaha! well, after a certain amount of points, it gives people a certain amount of clout. Low reppers, like to move in on other people's action.

Comment: @Darren oh, and to answer your question to Ravi; because, they either don't know or don't care. I have a feeling it's more of a "teeter-totter" effect.

Comment: @Ravi - Also see [What is a “protected” question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764); and [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)